# ¿Cómo hacer que una imagen insertada con ::after en un elemento <img> adapte su tamaño?

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente elemento html:

```
<div class="movie-box-container">
      <div class="movie-box" id="movie-box1">
        <figure class="movie-image-container">
          <img src="images/pelicula.jpg" alt="">
        </figure>
        <p class="movie-text"></p>
      </div>
```

En el cual aplico el siguiente estilo a figure y a img:

```
.movie-image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.movie-image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
```

Si lo hago así, todo correcto. Pero tengo 40 elementos de este tipo y para añadir el enlace de la imagen quiero usar ::after en la hoja de estilos en lugar de ponerlo directamente en el atributo url. Pero el problema de hacerlo así es que la imagen se muestra entera y no se adapta al contenedor.

```
.movie-image-container img::after {
  content: url("images/pelicula.jpg");
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?
Gracias ;)

Comment: no entiendo el por que es necesario usar un pseudo elemento `after`

Comment: Es una práctica y estoy aprendiendo... posiblemente no sea la mejor forma de hacerlo. Pero diseñé una estructura con muchos elementos mediante una abreviación emmet y luego pensé que añadirle el contenido sería fácil desde CSS.

Comment: los pseudo-elementos :`:after` y `::before` no se pueden usar en en la etiqueta `<img>`

Comment: Me funciona la edición del atributo `url` y me añade la imagen, pero luego ignora la configuración que le doy.

Comment: ¿Pero te funciona el `:after` en una imagen? ¿Puedes ponerlo en un snippet aqui? En principio no funciona en los elementos de reemplazo como `img`, `input`, `objetc`, etc. Creo que se podía conseguir que algunos navegadores lo acepten con algún truco extraño.

Comment: Tal cual lo describo arriba me añade la imagen y se visualiza aunque sin dejarse modificar (en Chrome). Quería probarlo sin usar JS pero al final me decido por hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: Pero en el ejemplo que pones la imagen del html y la del `::after` es la misma, Si está funcionando (yo no lo he conseguido) tendrias la misma imagen repetida. No entiendo que quieres hacer